# xcode check that the identity you selected is valid

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode

I am new to IOS App Development. While trying to distribute the app I made, I was notified that I need a 120x120 app icon for the iphone app. I went into images.xcassets and tried to import the icon.

But accidently removed the orginal "AppIcon" (nothing was in it though). Ever since that, Xcode will show "code signing operation failed: check that the identity you selected is valid" everytime I try to distribute the app even I have the "AppIcon"(don't know how to resume it so I just copy the .json file from a new project) there just as before.

Question: 1. How to solve this error?
2. how to correctly upload app icon?

Thanks

Comment: 1. Right click on the images.xassets screen then choose AppIcon. 2. Supply icon with the correct size.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I created another project rebuilt the app, and drag in corrected format of incons.